# R - Merging two data files based on partial matching of inconsistent full name formats

Tags: r, merge, string-matching, fuzzy-comparison

Here is my previous question reposted with R format.

I'm looking for a way to merge two data files based on partial matching of participants' full names that are sometimes entered in different formats and sometimes misspelled. I know there are some different function options for partial matches (eg agrep and pmatch) and for merging data files but I need help with a) combining the two; b) doing partial matching that can ignore middle names; c) in the merged data file store both original name formats and d) retain unique values even if they don't have a match.

For example, I have the following two data files:

File name: Employee Data (df1 in R)

```
       Full.Name Date.Started Orders
1  ANGELA MUIR     6/15/14 25     44
2  EILEEN COWIE      6/15/14      40
3  LAURA CUMMING     10/6/14      43
4    ELENA POPA       1/21/15     37
5 KAREN MACEWAN       3/15/99     39
```

File name: Assessment data (df2 in R)

```
           Candidate Leading.Factor SI.D SI.I
1         Angie muir              I   -3   12
2      Caroline Burn              S   -5   -3
3  Eileen Mary Cowie              S   -5    5
4         Elena Pope              C   -4    7
5     Henry LeFeuvre              C   -5   -1
6      Jennifer Ford              S   -3   -2
7       Karen McEwan              I   -4   10
8      Laura Cumming              S    0    6
9       Mandip Johal              C   -2    2
10   Mubarak Hussain              D    6   -1
```

I want to merge them based on names (Full Name in df1 and Candidate in df2) ignoring middle name (eg Eilen Cowie = Eileen Mary Cowie), extra spaces (Laura Cumming = Laura Cumming); misspells (e.g. Elena Popa = Elena Pope) etc.

The ideal output would look like this:

```
              Name      Full.Name         Candidate Date.Started Orders Leading.Factor SI.D SI.I
1    ANGELA MUIR    ANGELA MUIR          Angie muir   6/15/14 25     44              I   -3   12
2    EILEEN COWIE   EILEEN COWIE  Eileen Mary Cowie     6/15/14      40              S   -5    5
3    LAURA CUMMING  LAURA CUMMING     Laura Cumming     10/6/14      43              S    0    6
4      ELENA POPA     ELENA POPA         Elena Pope      1/21/15     37              C   -4    7
5   KAREN MACEWAN  KAREN MACEWAN       Karen McEwan      3/15/99     39              I   -4   10
6    Caroline Burn            N/A     Caroline Burn          N/A    N/A              S   -5   -3
7   Henry LeFeuvre            N/A    Henry LeFeuvre          N/A    N/A              C   -5   -1
8    Jennifer Ford            N/A     Jennifer Ford          N/A    N/A              S   -3   -2
9     Mandip Johal            N/A      Mandip Johal          N/A    N/A              C   -2    2
10 Mubarak Hussain            N/A   Mubarak Hussain          N/A    N/A              D    6   -1
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The only merging function I have experience with is merge but I'm not sure how to use that with the partial string matching code

Answer (score 3):

For a first pass, I would suggest a two-stage process.

First, clean your strings. Normalize the casing, strip out extra spaces, strip out any unwanted characters. A function I use for a fairly aggressive cleaning is below:

```
stringCleaning <- function(x) {
#   x <- stringr::str_trim(x)
#   x <- tolower(x)
#   x <- gsub("\\s+", " ", x)
#   x <- gsub("[^[:space:]A-z0-9]", "", x)
  stringr::str_trim(tolower(gsub("\\s+", " ", gsub("[^[:space:]A-z0-9]", "", x))))
}
```

This converts strings to lowercase, strips out any non-alphanumeric or string characters, strips out extra spaces, and removes spaces on either side of the string.

Two, use Levenshtein (or edit) distances to find your closest matches. The `stringdist` package includes a simple distance calculator to help you.

```
stringdist::stringdist('your mother', c("bellow", "your mom", 'yourmother'))
min(stringdist::stringdist('your mother', c("bellow", "your mom", 'yourmother')))
which.min(stringdist::stringdist('your mother', c("bellow", "your mom", 'yourmother')))
```

You can use this function to find the most appropriate match in another dataframe.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Jena Stars", "Gina Starz"))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("gina starz", "Jena starz  "))

df1$clean <- stringCleaning(df1$name)
df2$clean <- stringCleaning(df2$name)

df1$check <- df2$name[sapply(df1$clean, function(x) {
  which.min(stringdist::stringdist(x, df2$clean))
  })]
df1
```

A small example, but I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you, yes this is incredibly useful! Now i just need to merge the two files together based on the matching function that you created. however, I will need to merge them while keeping the unique rows that have no match in the other dataframe. I know I can use the all.x argument in merge but I'm not sure how to integrate the merge function with this string matching code.

Comment: I think this function should do it: merge(df1, df2, by.x = "check", by.y = "name", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE, sort = TRUE)

Comment: I have a question on the stringdist code above (or function in general). Using the current code in the answer, if I tried to match the name Wayne Sinclair with either Dan Inch or Wayne Danielson Sinclair, it would return a match to Dan Inch: min(stringdist::stringdist('Wayne Sinclair', c("Wayne Danielson Sincalir"))) = 11 while min(stringdist::stringdist('Wayne Sinclair', c("Dan Inch"))) = 9. Is there something I can do (maybe using the amatch function and weight parameter) to fix this and set a rule that says return an N/A to the match if it requires too much string editing?

Comment: @SonyaBendriem - interesting example! You can use weight parameters within the `stringdist` function itself in order to tell the algorithm to give more importance to deletions over swaps (for instance). That said, I would probably approach a dataset including this confounder by breaking the names down. I would try to identify first, middle, and last names by splitting the string at spaces and adding a simple algorithm to identify common suffixes.