# Merge data frames based on partial matches of address strings

Tags: r, merge, string-matching, fuzzy-comparison

I'm looking for a way to match two different address data frames. The both contain a string of text (the 'Line' column in my example), a postcode/zip code type identifier (the 'PC' column') and a unique Ref or ID code. I would need to resulting matches to be in a new data frame with a format along the lines of: DF1$Line, DF1$PD, DF2$Line, DF2$PD, Ref, ID and some sort of numeric detailing the strength of match (this is based on the example code below).

My actual dataset contains several thousand records and I have been playing with the idea of using the 'PC' column to subset both datasets and then perform some sort of matching along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671245/r-merging-two-data-files-based-on-partial-matching-of-inconsistent-full-name-f), but the resulting matches I get are completely wrong.

Here is a made-up dataset that resembles my data (in these examples the rows in each dataset correspond to each other, my real data is not formatted like this unfortunately).

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
Line = c("64 London Street, Jasper","46 London Road, Flat 2, Jasper","99 York Parade, Yorkie","99 Parade Road, Placename","29 Road Street, Townplace","92 Parade Street, Yorky"),
PC = c("ZZ1 4TY","ZZ1 4TY","PP1 9TR","ZZ1 4TY","PP1 9TR","PP1 9RT"),
Ref = c("123451","567348","23412","98734","43223","32453")
)
```

and

```
DF2 <- data.frame(    
Line = c("64 London St, Jasper","Flat 2, 46 Road, London, Jasper","99 York Parade, Yorky","99 Parade Road, Placenames","Flat 3, 29 Road Street, Townplace, Townplace","92 Street, Parade, Yorkie"),
PC = c("ZZ1 4TY","ZZ1 4TY","PP1 9TR","ZZ1 4TY","PP1 9TR","PP1 9RT"),
ID = c("ABGED","GGFRW","UYTER","RTERF","WERWE","OYUIY")
)
```

Any help resolving this would be very much appreciated, as would any metric that helps me quantify how precise the matches are. Thanks.

Comment: If `PC` are unique for each `Line` you don't need (to merge!) a fuzzy comparison. Just `merge(DF1, DF2, by = "PC")` and then subset by unique values of `Ref`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it very clear. PC are not unique, multiple different address strings in the Line column could have the same PC value.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `agrep` function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my base R solution let me know if I get it.

```
 DF3 <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = "PC")
 DF3[!duplicated(DF3$Ref) , ]
        PC                         Line.x    Ref                    Line.y    ID
1  PP1 9RT        92 Parade Street, Yorky  32453 92 Street, Parade, Yorkie OYUIY
2  PP1 9TR         99 York Parade, Yorkie  23412     99 York Parade, Yorky UYTER
4  PP1 9TR      29 Road Street, Townplace  43223     99 York Parade, Yorky UYTER
6  ZZ1 4TY       64 London Street, Jasper 123451      64 London St, Jasper ABGED
9  ZZ1 4TY 46 London Road, Flat 2, Jasper 567348      64 London St, Jasper ABGED
12 ZZ1 4TY      99 Parade Road, Placename  98734      64 London St, Jasper ABGED
```

Comment: Thank you. Although Line.y contains only 3 of the 6 addresses. I need a solution that does not duplicate the same address multiple times.

Comment: @Chris I am sorry but I really don't understand your point. Could you please provide a desired output?

Comment: The desired output in my example would look like at a cbind of DF1 and DF2. However, as my real data does not look like this I need a solution that will essentially read the strings in both Line columns and find the closest match. I thought the PC column could be used to subset the data before this takes place for each row as matching addresses will have the same values in the PC field.

Comment: well, why you just don't `cbind` and then subset? I mean, The only common column is `Line`? if the case you do need a fuzzy matching but if not the case there must be another way we are missing.

Comment: Because my actual data is not as nicely formatted as that. In the real dataset DF1 row 1 may correspond to DF row 62,349. The problem I have is that the strings in the Line columns are different for each dataset with some have additional commas or words the different way round for example. The only thing that is guaranteed to be the same between matching rows in each DF is the PC column.

Comment: sounds very complicated... well... @Chris at this point I can say only two words: Good Luck :D

Answer (score 0):

I would consider first evaluating potential matches using `agrep`:

```
for (i in 1:length(DF1$Line)) {
  matchDF1 <- agrep(pattern = DF1$Line[i], x = DF2$Line, max.distance = 0.5,
                    value = TRUE) 
}
```